# Laravel 5.2 : redirect user to login page after fail

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

How should i redirect user to login page after a failed login?
i tried in `AuthController` :

```
  protected $redirectTo ='/login';
protected $loginView = 'auth.login_register_form';
protected $loginPath = '/login';
```

but user does not redirected to `/login` page , he get redirected back to the page he was in before
of curse there is  a method in `AuthenticateUser.php` that serve as login fails method:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

but i'm not allowed to edit this method . this is one of laravel core files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you have to return him redirect (not just assign path to variable), for example

```
return redirect('/login');
```

If it's form with filled inputs you can do something like

```
return redirect('/login')->withInput();
```

In your example

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect('/login')
        ->withInput($request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->loginUsername() => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Are you talking  about `AuthController`?

Comment: Yes, if your validation fails add redirect to your desired page

Comment: thanks, so you mean there is no property to do the job as is for success login or logout  . i should write the method myself